# C++ hidden symbolic Links

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, symlink

I have 3rd party software which crashed recently . In the Crash log it's pointing to a symbolic link. But I can't seem to figure the location of this link. I know during runtime it unloads the copies of all references and source codes to this mount point. I need to get to one of it's references to learn the reason for a crash.

```
<ModuleName>C:\some software\QtCore4.dll</ModuleName>
<Filename>e:\somedir\qbasicatomic.h</Filename>
```

It crashed on the above module with reference as mentioned. Could some please point me in the right direction as to how C++ creates these symbolic (hidden) links, and how to access them.

I tried doing `dir /AL /s` but there is no clue for this dir on `e:`. Also I used `NTFSLinksView.exe`, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: If you are using Qt, you'll better question your own code rather than Qt (which is tested a lot and quite reliable and much less buggy than your code). So compile your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger**

Answer (score 1):

The debug data is describing the file location on the build machine.  The file is not present on your machine.

Try downloading qt to find it.